# Perform sum operation in jdbcTemplate using STS framework

Tags: java, groovy

I have to find sum(actual_effort) and sum(planned_effort) using jdbcTemplate for that I am doing below coding but I am getting null value for actual_effort as well as planned_effort, and remaining values are coming correctly. Please help me...

```
List<TaskDTO> getAllProjectsTaskReport(){
log.info(" Service getAllProjectsTaskReport");

String sql="select id,sum(actual_effort),actual_end_date,actual_start_date,code,created_date,description,name,sum(planned_effort),planned_end_date,planned_start_date,status,work_completed_percent,assigned_to_id,created_by_id,parent_task_code_id,project_id from task group by project_id";

List<TaskDTO> list  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,new BeanPropertyRowMapper(TaskDTO.class));
return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sql with select as

```
List<TaskDTO> getAllProjectsTaskReport(){
log.info(" Service getAllProjectsTaskReport");

String sql="select id,sum(actual_effort) as actual_effort,actual_end_date,actual_start_date,code,created_date,description,name,sum(planned_effort) as planned_effort,planned_end_date,planned_start_date,status,work_completed_percent,assigned_to_id,created_by_id,parent_task_code_id,project_id from task group by project_id";

List<TaskDTO> list  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,new BeanPropertyRowMapper(TaskDTO.class));
return list;
}
```